# Can anyone tell me what is Work or School Account in MVC or Web API project?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authentication, asp.net-web-api

I have created a web api project,after that i need to select the authentication type,i found the following authentication.
[image]

Just want to know what is its benifit of "Work or school account",how it will be helpfull for user.

Answer (score 0):

The template code for that option assumes Azure Active Directory is the identity provider.

Answer (score 0):

We can use this option when authentication is enabled via third party identity provider like microsoft, gmail, facebook, twitter, insta account or even on premise Active Directory. Basically a template with SSO implemented.